# Element <a> not allowed as child of element <dl> in this context - Validator Error

Tags: javascript, html, validation

After running w3Validator on HTML 5 (Experimental) windows-1252 encoding,
I got the following error -

> Line 11, column 20: Element a not
>   allowed as child of element dl in this
>   context. (Suppressing further errors
>   from this subtree.)

```
<a href="#link"><dt>Link</dt><dd>Sub heading of the link</dd></a>
```

If `<a>` can not contain child element `<dl>` then how should the code be used?

NOTE: the above code is used by js, so there sould not be major change in code.

UPDATE: the whole code is as below -

```
<div id="something">
    <dl>
        <a href="#link1"><dt>title1</dt><dd>Sub heading1</dd></a>
        <a href="#link2"><dt>title2</dt><dd>Sub heading2</dd></a>
        <a href="#link3"><dt>title3</dt><dd>Sub heading3</dd></a>
        <a href="#link4"><dt>title4</dt><dd>Sub heading4</dd></a>
        <a href="#link5"><dt>title5</dt><dd>Sub heading5</dd></a>
        <a href="#link6"><dt>title6</dt><dd>Sub heading6</dd></a>
    </dl>
</div>
```

Comment: You read it wrong. It says that `<a>` cannot be a child of `<dl>`, and you did not show us the surrounding code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All the answers posted so far are wrong.

Anchors (or `<a>` elements) are inline by default, yes — but you can change that by using some basic CSS:

```
a {
  display: block;
}
```

In addition to that, as of HTML5, block level anchors are allowed. This means you can do cool things like:

```
<a href="#">
 <h1>Foo</h1>
 <p>Bar</p>
</a>
```

And have your code validate as HTML5. (This code has always worked in browsers, it was just not valid before HTML5.)

The **real** reason it doesn’t validate (and thus, the answer to your question) is very simple: `<dt>` and `<dd>` elements may only appear as *direct children* of a `<dl>` element.

Answer (score 1):

A definition list has a very specific structure

```
<dl>
  <dt>Definition title<dt>
  <dd>Definition description </dd>

  <dt><a href='#'>Definition title</a><dt>
  <dd>Definition description </dd>

  <dt>Definition title<dt>
  <dd><a href='#'>Definition description</a></dd>
</dl>
```

<strike>The only place you can actually put the LINK is inside either the DT or the DD. If I remember correctly a DD is considered a block level element and doesn't go inside a LINK in any case.</strike>

**EDIT** : As @Mathias Bynens points out in the comments, *only* DT and DD elements may appear as direct child elements of a DL.

Also putting inline tags around block level elements are allowed in HTML5

Comment: Your last paragraph is incorrect. You could put an entire `<dl>` inside an anchor (`<a>`) if you wanted to. The real reason why it fails is that you can’t use a `<dl>` element can only have `<dt>` and `<dd>` elements as direct children.

Comment: @Mathias Bynens thanks for the heads up, I've corrected my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically it's an issue with [block and inline elements](http://www.webdesignfromscratch.com/html-css/css-block-and-inline/). The conventions are that you should not put a block element inside an inline element, an `<a>` tag is inline and a `<dl>` ( and the `<dt>` and `<dd>` elements that should be inside it) is block. What you are doing is akin to putting a `<strong>` or `<a>` element around `<form>` or `<div>`, which obviously doesn't seem right.

The 'answer' to your question is to put the `<a>` tag inside the individual `<dt>` and `<dd>` tags and only have the definition term and definition-definition tags inside your definition list.

**Disregard**: Didn't realise you were trying to validate HTML 5. In this case the answer is that you can't put anything other than `<dt>` and `<dd>` as direct children of `<dl>`.

Comment: HTML5 allows block level anchors, so your explanation doesn’t make any sense. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5581257/element-a-not-allowed-as-child-of-element-dl-in-this-context-validator-erro/5581416#5581416).

Comment: actually I am trying to get a block hover effect...If I place <a> individually them there is some disruption in animation by jquery.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see OP said HTML5! In that case it's probably just because OP isn't sticking to the`<dl>` format.